# How can I modify a CSS tag content? Without using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I work on a static web page that is supposed to help Chinese learners.
I paste below an extract of the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ma+Shan+Zheng&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pattaya&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Youdao-Dayou Cidian</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="words_en_style.css">
    <style>

      body {
        background-image: url("fond_caractères_transp.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-size: 100%;
      }

      .temp {
        background-color: lightcoral;
        margin-top: 80px;
      }
      .pinyin {
        font-family: "Pinyin Okay", "Pattaya", sans-serif;
        font-style: unset;
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
      .green {
        font-family: "Courier new", monospace;
        font-size: 3px;
        font-style: unset;
        opacity: 0;
        line-height: 0.6;
      .baratin {
        font-family: "Courier new", monospace;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      .nota {
        line-height: 0.6;
      }
      .commentaire {
        font-family: "Courier new", monospace;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 0.6;
      }
      .bluemark {
        color: rgb(43, 32, 201);
      }
      #shang {
        background-color: rgb(230, 240, 93);
        font-family: "Ma Shan Zheng", cursive;
        position: fixed;
        right: 1.4%;
        top: 98%;
        width: 8em;
        margin-top: -1.6em;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        animation: Test 1s infinite;
      }
      @keyframes Test {
        0% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
        opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
      h1 {
        color: rgb(241, 0, 133);
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgb(117, 190, 99);
        font-family: "Ma Shan Zheng", cursive;
        font-size: 68px;
        margin-top: 1.8%;
      }
      p {
        font-family: "Ma Shan Zheng", cursive;
        font-size: 26px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
      #tableaucomposants {
        width: 96%;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgb(204, 140, 163);
        font-family: "KaiTi Normal", cursive;
        font-size: 30px;
        background-color: rgb(245, 174, 196);
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 0.2%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: left;
        font-style: bold;
        padding-top: 1%;
        padding-left: 1.4%;
        padding-right: 1.4%;
        padding-bottom: 0.8%;
      }
      a:link {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Ma Shan Zheng", cursive;
        font-size: 26px;
      }
      #N°1,
      #N°5,
      #N°6 {
        width: 96%;
        font-family: "Ma Shan Zheng", cursive;
        font-size: 26px;
        background-color: rgb(245, 174, 196);
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 1%;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;
        text-align: left;
        font-style: bold;
        padding-top: 1%;  padding-left: 1.4%;  padding-right: 1.4%;  padding-bottom: 0.8%;
      }

      </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>有道-打有   词典</h1>

<section id="tableaucomposants">
  氵，<a href="#N°2"> 艹</a> ， <a href="#N°3"> 木</a>， <a href="#N°4"> 口</a>，
  <a href="#N°5">  钅 </a>，
  <a href="#N°6"> 扌</a>，   <a href="#N°6"> 亻</a>/<a href="#ren"> 人</a>.  <br>
  <span class="commentaire">Actually under construction :-) </span>
</section>

<!--     To fill  with existing id -->
<section id="N°1">
  <p> 氵<span class="baratin"> same as <a href="#shui"> 水</a>: Radical N° 85, not indecomposable,
      graphic component N° 43.
      876 characters in the Wenlin dictionary, 148 in this Youdao-Dayou lexicon. </span></p>
  <p class="nota">  <span class="commentaire">This element is a reference to the liquid (3 drops of
      water) and is
      always placed on the left of the character it builds. In this form, the third and last stroke is
      carried out going up
      from left to right, to chain the writing of the following component: it is a  ㇀
  <span class="pinyin">tí </span>
  <span class="green">. </span> 提. This is the most common radical, key, in combination.
  No word for this component.<br>
          <span class="green">. </span></span></p>
  <p><span class="baratin">Used as a radical in:</span> 澳，滨，波，泊，测，
      潮，沉，澄，池，淡，滴，淀，洞，渡，洱，法，泛，
      沸，浮，港，沟，灌，滚，海，汉，汗，涵，浩，河，洪，湖，滑，汇，混，
      浑，活，济，激，渐，江，浇，洁，津，浸，渴，溃，滥，浪，泪，淋，流，
      溜，漏，沦，洛，满，漫，没，泌，渺，漠，沫，泥，浓，派，潘，泡，漂，
      泼，浦，瀑，汽，漆，泣，浅，潜，清，渠，溶，汝，润，洒，沙，涉，深，
      沈，渗，湿，淑，滩，潭，汤，淌，涛，淘，滔，添，涂，湾，汪，温，沃，
      污，洗，溪，湘，消，泄，泻，汹，汛，涯，演，沿，淹，淹，洋，液，溢，
      泳，涌，游，油，渔，浴，源，渊，澡，泽，渣，沾，涨，浙，治，汁，滞，
      洲，注，滋.<br>      <span class="baratin">     139/ ... / 865.</span></p>
  <p><span class="baratin">Used as a component of an indecomposable: </span>.    </p>
  <p><span class="baratin">Used as a component of a character: </span>荡，范，鸿，酒，梁，茫，萍，染，
  烫.    </p>
</section>

<section id="N°5">
<p> 钅<span class="baratin"> same as </span>  金<span class="baratin">:  Radical N° 167,
     not indecomposable,
     graphic component N° 76.
     219 + 488 characters in Wenlin, 40 in this lexicon. </span></p>
 <p class="nota">  <span class="commentaire">This graphical element was obtained by compressing
         the character 金 on
         its width (Compare: 金, 釒, 钅 with 言, 訁, 讠). As 金 <span class="pinyin">jïn</span>,
         which means metal, gold, this component refers
         to the metal element. It is placed on the left of the characters it composes.
         No word for this component.<br><span class="green">. </span></span></p>
 <p><span class="baratin">Used as a radical in:</span> 铲，钞，锤，错，钓，钉，锻，锋，钢，钩，锅，键，
    锦，
    镜，链，铃，铝，锣，铭，铺，钱，铅，钦，锐，锁，铁，
    铜，锡，镶，销，银，镇，针，钟，铸，钻. <br>
    <span class="baratin"> as </span>金 <span class="baratin"> => </span>  鉴，金.    </p>
    <span class="baratin">     36 + 2 / 694.</span></p>
   <p><span class="baratin">Used as a component of an indecomposable: </span>.    </p>
   <p><span class="baratin">Used as a component of a character: as  </span> 钅  =>  衔.    </p>
 </section>

 <section id="N°6">
   <p> 扌<span class="baratin"> same as <a href="#shou"> 手/龵</a>:  Radical N° 64, not
      indecomposable, graphic component N° 19.
      566 characters in Wenlin, 151 in this lexicon. </span></p>
   <p class="nota">  <span class="commentaire">This element is a reference to the hand, or a manual
      gesture and
      is always placed, when used as a radical, on the left of the character it is composing.
      It represents a hand and its fingers apart. Surnamed  提手旁
      <span class="pinyin">tí</span><span class="pinyin">shôu</span><span class="pinyin">páng</span>,
      contained
      in the word 提 <span class="pinyin">tí</span> which means rising stroke from left to right, and
      of which the last stroke is just an example.
      No word for this component.<br>
      <span class="green">. </span></span></p>
    <p><span class="baratin">Used as a radical in:</span> 挨，按，把，拔，扒，
      摆，搬，扮，拌，报，抱，播，拨，搏，捕，擦，操，
      插，拆，抄，撤，扯，撑，撑，持，抽，摧，措，挫，打_，搭，担，挡，
      捣，抵，掉，抖，扶，抚，拂，搞，搁，拱，挂，拐，护，换，挥，技，挤，
      捡，拣，搅，接，揭，捷，据，拒，拘，捐，掘，抗，扛，控，扣，括，扩，
      拉，拦，捞，拢，搂，掠，抹，描，摸，挠，拟，捏，扭，挪，排，拍，抛，
      捧，批，披，拼，扑，抢，扰，扔，揉，撒，扫，摄，拾，授，摔，撕，搜，
      损，拓，抬，探，摊，掏，提，挑，挺，投，推，托，拖，挖，挽，握，捂，
      掀，携，押，掩，扬，摇，抑，拥，援，择，扎，摘，找，招，折，振，挣，
      指，执，掷，抓，撰，撞，捉.<br>
      才. <br>  <span class="baratin">     143/ ... / 579.</span></p>
    <p><span class="baratin">Used as a component of an indecomposable: </span>才.    </p>
    <p><span class="baratin">Used as a component of a character: </span> 垫，啦，啪，热，
      势，逝，哲，浙.    </p>
 </section>
 <button id="shang" > <a title="Tableau des Composants"
         href="#tableaucomposants"> 上  <span class="green">.... </span> <span class="baratin">  Haut</span>
   </a></button>
</body>
```

Actually, the pinyin class is working for all the five tones of the Chinese language: with a special font that can render äáâà ëéêè ïíîì öóôò üúûù and ÜÚÛÙ. There are now pedagogic methods that associate colors with Chinese tones to help to memorize them.

I want to associate red to the first tone ä, green to the second á, blue for the third â, and grey for the fourth à.

But I have to rewrite 4567 lines (x 2, EN and FR). A search for pinyin gives already 670 (1340) modifications to perform. This lexicon is not yet ended, but it is already a *big work* :-).

So *if* I can modify my only one class pinyin by the way of a few code lines, I save time and energy! Isn’t it that? The magical of code?
It looks like it would be possible with JavaScript using something like document.getElementsByTagName('pinyin') which would allow to test what is inside:

```
/ <span class="pinyin"> vowel to be tested /</span>
```

and function of the result allocates to the text the good color.

Is there an easier way to do that with PHP or just CSS?

Comment: Why to tag a question with JavaScript, if you don't want to use JavaScript?

Comment: CSS Is not going to be applied to individual characters

Comment: Am I correct that you want to partially automate editing the HTML that underlies your web page? Am I correct that you want to programmatically examine every element within a certain class and, based on the content within the element, add additional classes to that top-level class?

Comment: @Teemu : i am looking for something working in JS about the DOM :  document.getElementsByTagName('pinyin') :-)  this is why one tag is JS

Comment: @cssyphus : yes i want to add a text color in the class pinyin, a color function of the content within the element  :-)  and i wonder which way can help to do this, without using JS.  I am not computer scientist !  wouldn't that be possible in php ? now that php is able to work with classes and objects (which was not the case when i learnt php in 2001 :-( )  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use almost any language to do what you want to do, but each language has its speciality. PHP and Nodejs are back-end languages that work on the server - you don't need their server-side abilities but you can use their string-manipulation utilities to do what you need. You might find some challenges, though, uploading, transferring, and saving-out the edited files.

Similarly, javascript is a client-side language that runs in the browser. Still, you could use it to do this project. You might find some of the same challenges as with php.

On the other hand, there are a number of scripting languages that are almost tailor-made for your project. The goal is to choose the easiest and the most re-useable of the languages. These languages include Python, Perl, Windows Powershell, AutoHotKey (AHK), Wilson's WinBatch, etc. Personally, I've done massive projects in WinBatch* because it's so frickin' easy and has a decent help forum and loads of example code. (AHK is a freeware competitor to WinBatch that is more difficult to get started with, but is every bit as powerful). I've also done very significant projects in Python and find it almost as easy as WinBatch. A LOT depends on your operating system - WinBatch only works on Windows machines, but Python works everywhere.

My recommendation would be Python. There is tons of help available on StackOverflow, and the reusability factor is very high.

Your next consideration will be your IDE. WinBatch includes its own, quite dated, IDE but it does the job and allows stepping through your code. If using Python, my personal favorite (freeware) environments are VSCode and Notepad++. VSCode *(make sure you have the Python and CodeRunner extensions installed)* also allows stepping through code and is definitely the 2020 choice for IDE.

`*` *WinBatch is commercial software that allows you a 21-day trial license that is fully functional except for the compiler. You should have tons of time to complete your project and kick the tires. Disclaimer: I am a long time WinBatch user but have no affiliation with the company whatsoever.*

Comment: Hello :-) What you wrote is very interesting and almost very clear, but as i wrote above i am a newbie !  do you suggest me to write this in Python ? with regex to test letters in pinyin class tags and use getElementsByTagName('pinyin') in a python script ?

Comment: Yes, I suggest using either Python or WinBatch. Frankly, WinBatch will be easier - but Python will be a better language to know for the future (Python works on Apple / Linux / Windows whereas WinBatch is Windows only). The most important thing is to break your project up into "tasks" - the first task is: open your file, add one word to the top, save it again. Check that everything worked. Next task: read the entire file, line by line, saving each line into a new file so that at the end you have two files. You need to design this "plan" - actually write it down, each step. Then do it.

Comment: If you have any other questions, please feel free to ask. Remember that StackOverflow is a "game" that works by questions/answers. So ask LOTS of questions (generally, SO is designed for very specific programming questions). NEVER take downvotes personally - ignore them (try not to be downvoted, but dont let them stop you). Keep asking questions. And please remember to close questions by choosing a correct answer, and by upvoting helpful answers (you can do both at the same time). Checkmarks and upvotes cost you nothing, so be generous - they are why people answer the questions.

Comment: By the way, I mentioned that one of your tasks is to read/edit the file line by line. To me, that is how ***I*** think you will need to make the changes you must make. Line by line. That is just what I think, you might have another idea and your idea might work better. The most important thing is to break your project up into several steps, **write them down**, then go do your project step-by-step.

Comment: WinBatch or Python... Both will do the job, but Python will be more difficult, especially at the start. You'll be off and running with WB within minutes, and the "tech database" has example code for everything you want to do. WinBatch can do RegEx.. WinBatch is actually surprisingly powerful - I wrote [this app](http://www.quotetdn.com) in WinBatch. I've been planning for years to re-write it in Python but it is much more difficult to write in Python. WinBatch now costs $65 (I paid $500) and worth every penny. You do NOT need the compiler, but nice to have. The free trial ver is all you need.